# dup2 after Fd[0]!= STDIN_FILENO

Tags: c, linux, pipe

Can someone please explain the reasoning of using `dup2` after checking if `fd[0] != STDIN_FILENO`, because from what I understand `fd[0] != STDIN_FILENO` would fail and `dup2` would still return something other than `STDIN_FILENO`, just trying to understand some example code thank you, also if some one could explain the use of execlp for me to that would be awesome.

```
int fd[2];
pid_t pid;

if(argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Must be specify exactly 1 file\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    if(pipe(fd) < 0)
        exit(1);./ 

    pid = fork();

    switch (pid) {
        case -1:
            exit(1);
        case 0:
            close(fd[1]);
                        //here
            if(fd[0] != STDIN_FILENO) {
                if(dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO) != STDIN_FILENO)
                    exit(3);
                close(fd[0]);
            }
            if(execlp("tr", "tr", "[a-z]", "[A-Z]", (char *) 0) < 0)
                exit(4);
            break;

        default:
            close(fd[0]);
                        // and here
            if(fd[1] != STDIN_FILENO) {
                if(dup2(fd[1], STDIN_FILENO) != STDIN_FILENO)
                    exit(5);
                close(fd[1]);
            }
            if(execlp("cat", "cat", argv[1], (char *) 0) < 0)
                exit(4);
            break;
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: Does anyone understand why that code uses the *write* end of an *unidirectional* pipe as *stdin*? This code looks wrong.

Comment: @thejh Yeah, the default (parent) case it wrong ... those ought to be STDOUT_FILENO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The intent is to make stdin (STDIN_FILENO, which is 0) point to the file that fd[0] points to (the read side of the pipe). First check that they aren't already the same ... if they are, the code would dup 0 to 0 and then close 0 -- not good. If they aren't the same, use dup2 to make STDIN_FILENO point where fd[0] points. If dup2 succeeds, it returns its second argument, so the check is against that with a call to exit if dup2 failed.

You write

> From what I understand fd[0] != STDIN_FILENO would fail

It's not at all clear why you "understand" this. It only fails if fd[0] contains STDIN_FILENO (i.e., 0), but it isn't likely to since it contains a file descriptor allocated by the `pipe` call.

> dup2 would still return something other than STDIN_FILENO

dup2 returns its second argument if it succeeds. It won't return something other than STDIN_FILENO unless it fails -- and why would it? -- and in that case it returns -1.

Comment: That makes total sense thank you, if you don't mind can you explain the exclep since I can grasp your explanation. Thank you.

Comment: @cincybengal The first argument to execlp is the filename (path) of the program to be run. The rest of the arguments are the command line arguments for the program, the first of which is conventionally the name of the program -- that's why there are two "tr", one for the program's path and the other the program's name. If you want to knwo what tr does and how to interpret its argument, read its man page.

Comment: so its just executing the tr program and using the rest as the command line args and instead of null its (char *) 0, Thank you for your patience, it drives me nuts when I cant understand code.

Comment: @cincybengal execlp is a varargs function so there's no prototype for the argument types, thus they must be specified correctly. If NULL is defined simply as 0 (as it often is), then that would pass an int 0 rather than a pointer 0, causing a big problem if ints and pointers aren't the same size.

Comment: "if they are, the code would dup 0 to 0 and then close 0 -- not good."
From the man: "If oldfd is a valid file descriptor, and newfd has the same value as oldfd, then dup2() does nothing, and returns newfd.". http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html
Am I missing something?

Comment: @n0p Um, yes, `dup2(0, 0)` would do nothing, but that's irrelevant -- it's the `close` call that would be the problem without the check.

Comment: Ah, ok, now I see. I thought you were about dup2's silent close and only now noticed the "the CODE would" part.

Comment: @n0p It helps the read the question before commenting ... in this case a request to explain the posted code. And since this question and answer are 4 years old, I had to read and understand my answer -- something you didn't bother to do -- in order to respond to your comment.

Comment: @JimBalter I think you are somewhat exaggerating. You can't say that I didn't read the question just because I was not able to tell from your answer that you are about the `close(fd[0]);` and not the silent _close_ that `dup2` does, which I think you can agree makes a misleading context. Your comment makes it more clear than it is in the answer. Also the request was not directed specifically to you. Anyway, thank you for the comment, sorry for taking your time.

Comment: ^ No, I was not exaggerating. There is no misleading context in my answer, which is crystal clear. (Thus the OP wrote "That makes total sense thank you".) *Obviously* it is `close 0`, not the harmless noop `dup 0 to 0`, that is "not good". "Also the request was not directed specifically to you" -- LOL! Obviously not true (and irrelevant in any case).

Answer (score 1):

[`execlp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp) basically executes a program. That program will read its input from `STDIN_FILENO` (in other words, fd 0). The [`dup2`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2) and [`close`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2) syscalls are used to move the `fd[0]` or `fd[1]` file descriptor to that number.

Comment: so what your saying is that when f[0] gets closed in the parent then dup2 will launch in the child and then excelp will execute in the parent ? Im sorry if this is trivial but why (char *) 0

Comment: @cincybengal Read the execlp manmage I linked to. `(char*)0` is used here instead of `NULL` to terminate the argument list.

Answer (score 1):

The checking on `fd[0] != STDIN_FILENO` is a defensive programming practice, since normally the standard input and standard output have been previously open, although if they had both been closed before you do the `pipe()` call, `pipe()` would have allocated the two descriptors to the pipe (Note when a pipe is created, the file descriptors used for the two ends of the pipe are the next lowest-numbered descriptors), so the checking will come into making sense.

Answer (score 0):

This program is going to run cat in parent process, and run tr in child process, and it want cat's output to be read by tr.

At beginning, it opens a pipe, parent will write to fd[1], and child will read from fd[0], so that parent can write data to child.

In parent, it dup fd[1] to stdin; and in child it dup fd[0] to stdin.

In child, execlp to run tr, tr will read from stdin, and since stdin has been dup as fd[0], so it actually read what cat's output from the pipe.

`execlp()` run a new executable in current process. You may `man execlp` for its argument detail.

Comment: but why is the dup2 calls necessary, and in the child the dup should not be called unless fd[1] has not been initialized properly, I man paged execlp and i still dont understand what exactly is going on, but thanks for the help

Comment: Why the dup2 is neccessary? Because stdin is 0, tr only knows stdin, it doesn't realize fd[0]. So it has to dup fd[0] to stdin.